# Crop Face OpenCv

Tags: opencv, crop, face-detection, stasm

Currently, I am working on an Age Estimation algorithm (using Biologically Inspired Features) and managed to use an ASM (STASM).

Is there any way that I can crop the face region using the landmarks/co-ordinates returned by STASM for the face (i.e. non rectangular)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To crop an image using the landmark points of an Active Shape Model you should use a Piecewise-Affine Warp technique, as the one described by Matthews and Baker: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/AP06/Papers/matthews_ijcv_2004.pdf

Cropping the image texture delimited by the ASM points with this kind of methods is actually the basis of the well-known Active Appearance Model -related techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am currently researching on it.